Finite Galois extension $K | F$ and $\prod_{\sigma} (x - \sigma(\alpha))$.
Let $K | F$ be a finite Galois extension, $E$ an intermediate field, $\alpha \in E$. It is known that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is
$$
m_{\alpha, F} (x) = \prod_{c \in C} (x - c),
$$
where $C := \{ \sigma(\alpha) \mid \sigma \in \operatorname{Hom}_{F} (E, K) \}$ is the collection of Galois conjugates of $\alpha$. That is to say, $m_{\alpha, F} (x)$ is the "separable part" of
$$
f(x) = \prod_{\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}_F (E, K)} (x - \sigma(\alpha)).
$$
My question is that: What is $f(x)$? Since
$$
\deg f(x) = | \operatorname{Hom}_F (E, K) | = [E : F] = \deg_F E,
$$
I guess:
Conjecture. $f(x)$ is just the charactersitic polynomial of $\alpha$, as an $F$-linear map from $E$ to $E$ (mapping $x$ to $\alpha x$).
I give a sketch of my "proof".
Let $L_\alpha \in M_n (F)$ be a matrix of $\alpha \in \operatorname{End}_F (E)$. Obviously, the minimal polynomial of $L_\alpha$ is exactly $m_{\alpha, F} (x)$, which splits completely over $K$. Therefore $L_\alpha$ is diagnozable in $M_n (K)$, which implies that
$$
\det(xI - L_\alpha) = \prod_{i = 1}^{r} (x - c_i)^{d_i},
$$
where $c_1, \dots, c_r$ are distince elements in $\left\{ \sigma(\alpha) \mid \sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K | F) \right\}$. With that fact that $\det(xI - L_\alpha) \in F[x]$ and Galois correspondence, one can easily show that $d_1 = \cdots = d_r =: d$. In particular,
$$
\det(xI - L_\alpha) = m_{\alpha, F} (x)^d.
$$
With the similar arguement, $f(x) = m_{\alpha, F} (x)^d$. Hence $f(x) = \det(xI - L_\alpha)$.
My Question. I'm not sure whether my "proof" is right. It seems reasonable but I cannot find this conclusion in any textbook on abstract algebra. If it is correct, I wonder if there is any "more elegant" proof and any lecture notes or textbooks about it.

The polynomial $f$ can be obtained way easier by the orbit stabilizer theorem if $E/F$ is normal (thanks @Long-Ping Li for pointing that out), i.e. let $G=\operatorname{Hom}_F(E,K)$, then
$$|G\cdot \alpha|=\frac{|G|}{|\operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha)|}$$ and $$f(x)=m_{\alpha,F}(x)^{|\operatorname{Stab}_G(\alpha)|}.$$ For references of this all books covering Group actions should do. A book about Galois Theory I like is Cox's book "Galois Theory".
Btw, your proof looks correct and is more general. If you want a reference for the fact that $f$ is the characteristic polynomial I cannot really help you, but it is considered folklore I guess. However, if I remember correctly, you can get an alternative proof of that by studying the rational canonical form of matrices.

Thank you for taking time to write. There are some points I don't really understand. $M := \operatorname{Hom}_F (E, K)$ is a monoid instead of a group. Does orbit-stab theorem hold here? And which set is the one on which $M$ acts?
