Minimal polynomial and product over conjugate elements
It has been discussed over and over again on this site that if $F(\alpha)/F$ is a galois extension with galois group $G$ then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is exactly $\prod_{\sigma\in G}(x-\sigma(\alpha))$. And I'm able to prove this result.
What if $K/F$ is a galois extension and $\alpha\in K$ (not necessarily primitive element)? I was told that if minipoly of $\alpha$ is $m(x)$ then $\exists t\in\Bbb N^*$ s.t. $\prod_{\sigma\in G}(x-\sigma(\alpha))=m(x)^t$. I believe this is also duplicated but I spent some hours failing to find it on this site.
I think I need to split the extension to: $K/F(\alpha)/F$. Then $m(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(F(\alpha)/F)}(x-\sigma(\alpha))$. But generally there's nothing much I can say about the relationship between $Gal(F(\alpha)/F)$ and $G$, since the former is neither a subgroup nor a quotient group of $G$. I'm stuck.

I think I was wrong about the minipoly of $\alpha$ since $F(\alpha)/F$ need not to be galois. If it is, I believe I can prove this by applying coset decomposition.

Hope this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4969110/finite-galois-extension-k-f-and-prod-sigma-x-sigma-alpha/4969141

You are close. The minimal polynomial is
$$m(x) = \prod_{\sigma \in Hom_F(F(\alpha), K)} (x - \sigma(\alpha)).$$
where $Hom_F(F(\alpha), K)$ is all the $F$-embeddings of $F(\alpha)$ into $K$.
If you consider
$$\prod_{\sigma \in Gal(K/F)} (x - \sigma(\alpha)),$$
the issue is that $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha$ can happen, so there are duplicates/multiplicity. $K$ being Galois implies that the multiplicity is the same for each root in the minimal polynomial, and you actually have
$$\prod_{\sigma \in Gal(K/F)} (x - \sigma(\alpha)) = m(x)^t$$
where $t = [K:F(\alpha)]$.
